# Why does MPI_Send accept void * source?

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I am wondering why the signature of `MPI_Send` is as below:

```
int MPI_Send(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag,
  MPI_Comm comm)
```

The first parameter is of type `void *`. Why is the first parameter of type `void *` rather than `const void *`. Will `MPI_Send` modify the source?

I ask such kind of question because I use MPI with C++ and pass `message.c_str()` to MPI_Send function where `message` is of type `std::string`. In this way, the compiler complains.

Comment: You are referring to an old (pre-3.0) MPI specification. In the current version of the standard (MPI 3.0), the C language binding for `MPI_SEND` has the `const` modifier present in the `buf` argument.

Comment: Fortran did/could modify the send buffer.  This was clarified in the 3.0 standard (and may have been mentioned in the 2.2 standard) that the implementation can not modify the send buffer, even with Fortran.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will MPI_Send modify the source?

No, it won't.

> My question is why the first parameter is of type void * rather than const void *.

Bad design.

The first versions of MPI were released after C has been standardized in 1989 and `const` available as a standard.

A proposal to add the missing `const` to `MPI_Send` and other MPI functions was submitted and accepted for future MPI-3.

https://svn.mpi-forum.org/trac/mpi-forum-web/ticket/140

Comment: I believe some MPIs at one time took advantage of the non-`const`ness by modifying endianness in-place.

Comment: MPI-3 is now finished and compliant implementations should include the const now. I know it's in MPICH. I'm not sure about others (Open MPI, etc.)

Comment: Indeed, @Edric, in-place data transformations were allowed until MPI-3. I don't know which implementations actually did anything with this freedom.